# Object doesn't show in camera viewport or on render

Tags: rendering, texturing

So, I'm having this weird issue where my object doesn't even show up on any renders I try to create.

This is the object in textured view on the 3D Viewport.
[image]

And here's what shows up on the camera viewport.

[image]

I've made up UV textures for it, applied them to each part of the model, linked the UV maps to each texture and it still shows up as nothing on the render. The camera viewport is just staring at blank space. I've made sure every single mesh in the scene is visible and on the same layer, so I'm really uncertain about what's causing this issue.

I'll see if I can post my blend file for my project.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a single model like that shouldn't be larger than the default grid. While the marked duplicate should fix your problem, simply scale down the model and the problem will go away just the same.

Comment: Damn, it really was that simple. Does the grid mark out the boundaries of the render or something?

Comment: No, not really, the default clipping size encompasses about that much area.